# Cannot Print over USB cable for Jiose J500 Label Printer

Tags: 18.04, usb, printing

The device is plugged in via USB and identifies itself as a Generic J500 in the Printer Settings, but when I try to print a label, the job ends up in the queue for another device, even though all other printers are not currently plugged in.

Comment: Manage your printers through the CUPS web interface at `http://localhost:631`

Comment: No answer for this yet? Just bought one and it's showing up as a generic text printer. Not a lot of details out there so far. :/

Comment: I never got it working so I returned it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ask customer service to send you a driver (with deb format).

Before I've tried to make Jiose J500 work with the PDD driver which integrated in CUPS. CPCL and EPL2 Zebra works, but not properly. With CPCL driver you can print, but not all the setting can be changed and the darkness is very low. With EPL2 driver you can change the settings, but printer will print only half of the label. I found the `cupsModelNumber` in PDD driver determines whether Jiose J500 works. It can be only set to 17 or 19, which makes printer works like with EPL2 or CPCL driver.